# Redrawing SVG on resize

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to redraw an SVG chart on window resize within d3, but without using the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` parameters (I didn't like how they treated text).

I'm also trying to stick with d3's databinding design via Bostock's [suggestion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/Rlv0O8xsFhs/UpS4OqV3Zx8J) when appending a single element (not based on backed data).

I have something that boils down to this ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/3dgn5pz8/)). However the SVG element's width/height never get updated.

### HTML

```
<div class="chart-container">
    <button class="user-option">Some User Options</button>
    <div class="svg-container"></div>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
    draw();
});

function draw() {
    var container = d3.select('.chart-container');
    var drawWidth = Math.round(0.80 * container.node().clientWidth);
    var drawHeight = Math.round(drawWidth * (3 / 4)); // Fixing a 4/3 aspect ratio

    /*
     * Use an inner g element as the SVG canvas in order to set and forget margins.
     * See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563
     */
    var margin = {
        top: 10,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 40
    };
    var width = drawWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = drawHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = container.select(".svg-container").selectAll('svg')
            .data([0]) // Single data element to create SVG if it doesn't exist
        .enter().append("svg")
            .attr("width", drawWidth)
            .attr("height", drawHeight)
        .append("g")
            .attr("class", "canvas")
            // jsFiddle doesn't translate correctly, maybe because of frames???
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    console.debug(svg.node()); // null on resize???

    // Add some random SVG element
    svg.selectAll('rect')
            .data([0]) // Single data element to create SVG if it doesn't exist
        .enter().append('rect')
            .attr({
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                width: drawWidth - margin.right - margin.left,
                height: drawHeight - margin.bottom - margin.top
            });
}
```

Comment: is the problem getting the var svg not to be null on resize?

Comment: The ultimate problem is the `svg` element not resizing (i.e. the `width` and `height` never get updated). However I think it's related to the fact that `var svg` is null when resizing (since all subsequent selections are then empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, I was able to get to the correct solution from all of your answers! However, neither answer was able to update the SVG on resize **AND** keep the `svg` variable as the `g` element (to stick with the [margin convention](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563)). I ended up doing

```
// Create SVG element (if it doesn't exist)
var svg = container.select(".svg-container").selectAll('svg').data([null]);
svg.enter().append("svg");
svg.attr({width: drawWidth, height: drawHeight}); // apply to enter + update selections

// Create g element (if it doesn't exist) and remap the svg variable
svg = svg.selectAll(".canvas").data([null]);
svg.enter().append("g") // apply to enter selection only
    .attr("class", "canvas")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Comment: I would probably use two different variables, `svg` for the SVG element and `grp` for the main group. If you absolutely have to keep the `svg` variable assigned to the group, you can change the first `svg` for `svgContainer` or something like that.

Comment: I'm also not not sure I'm crazy about having to bind the data to both the `svg` and the `g` elements but I need to think about whether that's actually an issue.

Answer (score 3):

The root problem here is that your svg variable is not being assigned the `<svg>` element selection, it's being assigned the end result of the chained method calls, which the first time round is the `<g>` element, and after that is empty because there's no 'enter' selection.

So first thing to do is change to

```
var svg = container.select(".svg-container").selectAll('svg').data([0]);
// now you have a reference to the svg selection
```

On first execution, the update selection will be empty and the enter selection will have a single element. You then bind this to a new `<svg>` element:

```
svg.enter()
    .append("svg")
    .append("g")
// note that from this point you're setting attributes on the <g>, not the <svg>
        .attr("class", "canvas")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

This append operation also adds the element to the update selection stored in `svg`.

On resize, the enter selection will be empty, but the update selection in `svg` will already contain the existing `<svg>` element. So either way, at this point you can set attributes on the `svg` selection - it will work for both cases.

```
svg.attr("width", drawWidth)
   .attr("height", drawHeight);
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3dgn5pz8/5/

Comment: Thanks, this works but ends up duplicating the update code (and not setting the svg variable as the g element). I ended up doing something slightly different.

Comment: @lebolo Good points. I've updated the answer to remove the duplication, but the point about the margin convention is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

@Pablo Navarro's answer is close the only issue is that svg on the redraw will not be your svg element but an array, use the same technique of separating the two executions but specifically select your svg again to change the width and height

```
var svg = container.select(".svg-container").selectAll('svg')
      .data([0]) // Single data element to create SVG if it doesn't exist
      .enter().append("svg")
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "canvas")
      // jsFiddle doesn't translate correctly, maybe because of frames???
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

then

```
container.select(".svg-container").select('svg').attr("width", drawWidth).attr("height", drawHeight)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLvuq0Lm/9/

Comment: Thanks, however the `svg` variable is empty on resize (empty enter selection) and is used later in the code (my fault for not adding that to the question). I ended up doing something slightly different in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the width and height of the svg element on enter, if the element already exists, it isn't updated. Try updating the element after the creation of the element (and the child group):

```
  var svg = container.select(".svg-container").selectAll('svg')
      .data([0]) // Single data element to create SVG if it doesn't exist
      .enter().append("svg")
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "canvas")
      // jsFiddle doesn't translate correctly, maybe because of frames???
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.attr("width", drawWidth).attr("height", drawHeight)
```

Regards,

Comment: This didn't work because the `svg` variable was empty on resize (empty enter selection).